# Which one is better between predis and phpredis?

Tags: predis, phpredis

*Which one should I choose and why between predis and phpredis ?I am using NGINX and Codeigniter.Thanks in advance*

Comment: I find the solution in the given link

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Redis-How-does-PRedis-compare-with-phpredis

Comment: [primarily opinion-based] Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 22):

I'll consider that your concern is performance and you mean "Which is faster?".

The short answer is "**PhpRedis**".

PhpRedis is a PHP extension (written in C) and Predis is a PHP package (written in PHP).

Based on many benchmarks like the mentioned link below, PhpRedis is about 6 times faster than Predis.
It's recommended to use PhpRedis if performance is a concern to your service.

Useful links:

[PhpRedis vs Predis: Comparison on real production data](https://medium.com/@akalongman/phpredis-vs-predis-comparison-on-real-production-data-a819b48cbadb)

Comment: PhpRedis is about 6x faster then Predis - https://medium.com/@akalongman/phpredis-vs-predis-comparison-on-real-production-data-a819b48cbadb . Howeverm if you're on a shared hosting, the only option would probably be Predis as a PHP package.

Comment: "Based on many benchmarks"... Only one is linked. Which are the others?

Answer (score 4):

It is worth noting that aside from library performance considerations, PHPRedis is presently lagging behind Predis in adding Redis 7 feature support (which I was looking for), so timing of your project implementation can also be a factor.

Comment: I'm curious, is there a specific reason/feature you need(ed) to support Redis 7 for?

Comment: @HashimAziz, yes, if I recall correctly, I was looking to use the Redis 7 Functions capability.